# \n is not working in java servlet program

Tags: java, servlets

here i'm just entering the username and password through .jsp file and print the username and pasword in different lines.

```
package pack123;
public class Loginpg extends HttpServlet{

    public void service (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        String username=request.getparameter("uname"); 
        String pass=request.getparameter("pwd"); 
        pw.println("the username is "+username+"\n"); 
        pw.println("the username is "+pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your text _and_ your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the results of servlet execution are returned to the browser, which formats and displays the output as HTML.

in HTML newlines (\n) in text have no meaning (see rogue's comment below for more info). try printing out an html break:

```
<br />
```

like so:

```
pw.println("the username is "+u+"<br />");
pw.println("the username is "+p);
```

Comment: Have no meaning except in specific situations, such as code blocks or `<pre>` formatted text, etc.

Comment: In fact, `pw.println("the username is "+u+"<br />\n");` Adds two new lines, since it is a `println`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - youre right. sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Newline doesn't matter to HTML. In fact,

```
pw.println("the username is "+u+"\n"); // <-- two new lines.
```

I think you wanted

```
pw.println("the username is "+u+"<br/>");
```

Even if `u` is null, you'll be getting a new line.